# Cross origin AJAX request with JSON breaks when authentication is required

Tags: php, ajax, json, jsonp, cors

I am trying to make an AJAX call to a PHP file on a different site:

```
$.ajax({                                      
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'http://user:password@www.myurl.com/myphpfile.php',
    data: {
        records: JSON.stringify(workingarray),
        account: account,
    },

    complete: function(response) {
        var parsedresponse = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response)).responseText.split("<br>");
        otherFunction(parsedresponse);
    }
});
```

My PHP file:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$records = json_decode($_GET['records']);
$account = $_GET['account'];

 .....[LOGIN AND SQL QUERY].....

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo json_encode($row['Some columns']."<br>", JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    }

$conn->close();
?>
```

This all worked great until I noticed I hadn't actually turned on authentication. Once I did that, the whole thing just broke down, and I always get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://user:password@www.myurl.com/myphpfile.php (...) . No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://originurl.co.uk' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

As you will see from my PHP code however, there IS a header present. I have also tried adding the following 2 lines to my .htaccess:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
```

With frustratingly little effect, which is to say, no effect whatsoever.

I have attempted to convert the datatype to JSONP, but I am not really sure how to go about doing this... I have tried the following changes:

```
$.ajax({                                      
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'http://user:password@www.myurl.com/myphpfile.php?callback=?',
    data: {
        records: JSON.stringify(workingarray),
        account: account,
    },

    complete: function(response) {
        var parsedresponse = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response)).responseText.split("<br>");
        otherFunction(parsedresponse);
    }
});
```

My PHP file:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('content-type: application/jsonp; charset=utf-8');

...

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $_GET['callback'] . "(" . json_encode($row['Some columns']."<br>", JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) . ")";
    }

$conn->close();
?>
```

This doesn't result in an error in the console as far as I can see, but the only thing I could make sense of in the response was this:

> status: 200
>
> statusText: "load"

(I added a `console.log(parsedresponse)` line to the `complete:` function for debugging purposes, but I must admit I am not entirely sure how to interpret most of what I am seeing.)

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated because this is causing me a lot of frustration.

Comment: It's probably the OPTION request failing, not the actual GET. Check if the pre-flight is returning 401 or the GET.

Comment: Thank you for responding, my apologies however, I'm not really sure how to do what you are suggesting.

Comment: When CORS occurs, 2 seperate request are send,(OPTIONS and GET) not just one.(only normal GET). Use a sniffer to see which one is failing with a HTTP 401 response code. (you can use Fiddler or something similar to sniff this).

Comment: It is far to be safe that user name, and password are transmitted with no encryption from client to a server and also passed in url !!!

Comment: Marvin, thank you for that, I will look into that this afternoon. Halayem, I am aware that basic auth is not ideal, security wise, but there is no particularly sensitive information in the password protected folders. That said I would prefer to use a more secure method nonetheless. Do you have any suggestions? Would using HTTPS help? Although if I do this I will need to go the JSONP route definitely as the origin is not HTTPS. I have considered also unsecuring the folder and passing the DB login information as part of the AJAX call but I'm not sure if this is more secure or not...

Comment: I have installed Fiddler and couldn't find the OPTION request... Nonetheless this did help in resolving the issue as I was able to view the response that wasn't showing up in the console, presumably due to my use of `complete` rather than `success`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have solved the problem - I have not quite fully rewritten the application but I am able to make the call and get a response so it should all be plain sailing from here on out (famous last words, haha).

Anyway, the changes I made were as follows - I firstly switched `complete` for `success` in the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({                                      
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'https://user:password@www.myurl.com/myphpfile.php?callback=?',
    data: {
        records: JSON.stringify(workingarray),
        account: account,
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        otherFunction(response);
    }
});
```

And then, and I think this was probably the main issue, I had to rewrite this part of the PHP file...

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo json_encode($row['Some columns']."<br>", JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    }
```

...to become:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rows = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = array('data' => $row['Some columns']);
    }

echo $_GET['callback'] . "(" . json_encode($rows, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) . ")";
```

...as obviously (in retrospect) my previous method was returning multiple functions with the same name.

I have also changed the request URL to https, which should be secure enough for the intended use, I think.

Anyway hope someone finds my experience useful.